# How does map know what is the key

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a csv file

text|text|key|text|text
text|text|key|text|text
text|text|key|text|text
text|text|key|text|text

and a java file

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class MTransactionPerDay implements Mapper<WritableComparable, Text, Text, Text>{

    public void map(WritableComparable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> outputCollector, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    }
```

My question is. How do I tell map method that the third field is the key?

Edit

This solved my problem

```
public void map(WritableComparable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> outputCollector, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        //split string
        String[] row = value.toString().split("[|]");
        //define key value pairs
        Text keyString = new Text(row[3]);
        Text valueString = new Text(row[2]);
        //result
        outputCollector.collect(keyString, valueString);
    }
```

But raised another question. I know map accepts a file and returns key/value pairs. What is this for then **WritableComparable key**?

In fact I wrote a test

```
@Test
    public void testMapReduce() {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\WorkSpace\\");
        mapReduceDriver.addInput(new LongWritable(1), new Text("0|9050000001|20160125204123"));
        mapReduceDriver.addInput(new LongWritable(1), new Text("0|9050000001|20160125204123"));
        mapReduceDriver.addInput(new LongWritable(1), new Text("0|9050000002|20160125204123"));
        mapReduceDriver.addOutput(new Text("9050000001"), new IntWritable(2));
        mapReduceDriver.addOutput(new Text("9050000002"), new IntWritable(1));
        mapReduceDriver.runTest();
    }
```

And had to add this there

```
mapReduceDriver.addInput(new LongWritable(1), new Text("0|9050000001|20160125204123"));
```

even thought I never used that key.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement custom RecordReader.

For example:
Hadoop has implemented a record reader for TextInputFormat.It reads lines of text files. The key it emits for each record is the byte offset of the line read (as a LongWritable), and the value is the contents of the line up to the terminating '\n' character (as a Text object).

[Refer this to develop custom record reader](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat)